# PHP $_Request gets value but $_GET does not

Tags: php, get, request

I have the following HTML form with PHP:

```
<form name="login" action="http://oz-local.com:8080/_admin/login.php?action=process" method="post">

<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>

<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>

</form>
```

When I'm trying to get the value of "action" using `$_GET['action']`, it's empty. But when I use `$_REQUEST['action']`, I get the value "process".

The script I use for this is:

```
echo (isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? 'Yes': 'No');
echo '<br>R: ' . $_REQUEST['action'] . '<br><br>';
echo (isset($_GET['action']) ? 'Yes': 'No');
$gA = $_GET['action'];
echo '<br>gA: ' . $_GET['action'];
echo '<br><br>';
echo (isset($_POST['action']) ? 'Yes': 'No');
$pA = $_POST['action'];
echo '<br>pA: ' . $_POST['action'];
echo '<br><br>';
echo (isset($_COOKIE['action']) ? 'Si': 'No');
$cA = $_COOKIE['action'];
echo '<br>cA: ' . $_COOKIE['action'];
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
echo 'M: ' . $method;
```

Is it normal?
This does not making any sense!!

Any help to clarify my doubt is really appreciated.

Comment: *"but $_GET doesn't it"* - which is normal since you're using a POST method.

Comment: @user6184870 please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using POST method in form action attribute,
`<form name="login" action="http://oz-local.com:8080/_admin/login.php?action=process" method="post">`

You can get all values using `$_POST`, you don't need `$_GET`.
Because `$_POST` is more secure to use than, `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

When submitting HTML forms, there are two methods one can use: GET and POST. In your HTML, you've specified that the form should use:

```
method="post"
```

This means PHP's `$_GET` array will not contain it, instead it is accessible via either `$_POST['action']` or `$_REQUEST['action']`.

`$_REQUEST` is a combination of *both* GET and POST values.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on below

**$_GET** retrieves variables from the querystring, or your URL.

**$_POST** retrieves variables from a POST method, such as (generally) forms.

**$_REQUEST** is a merging of $_GET and $_POST. It retrieves variable of GET as well as POST METHOD.